# How to pass userid and password in twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I get the following Exception when I execute the following code. Also I would like to know how to pass userid and password using twitter4j?

**Exception :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.Twitter.<init>(Ltwitter4j/conf/Configuration;Ltwitter4j/http/Authorization;)V
        at twitter4j.TwitterFactory.getInstance(TwitterFactory.java:151)
        at twitter4j.TwitterFactory.getInstance(TwitterFactory.java:81)
        at twitter.UpdateStatus.main(UpdateStatus.java:38)
```

My code:

```
package twitter;

import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import twitter4j.http.AccessToken;

public final class UpdateStatus {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String testPost = "hello from otc";
        String consumerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String consumerSecret = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
        String accessToken = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
        String accessSecret = "fffffffffffffffffffffffffff";

        // ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        //
        // cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        // .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
        // .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
        // .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
        // .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessSecret);

        try {
            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory();
            Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
            AccessToken accestoken = new AccessToken(accessToken, accessSecret);

            // twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accestoken);
            Status status = twitter.updateStatus(testPost);
            System.out.println("it worked!");
            if (status.getId() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Error occured while posting tweets to twitter");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is seen in your code also,
using twitter4j there is no need to pass username and password.

Consumer key/secret and token key/secret are enough to identify the user.